Handling Android widgets in Kotlin Compose
Is it possible that there is no official documentation how to use widgets in Kotlin Compose? I found a few resources but nothing official.
How can I load widgets? How to size them? How to reconfigure them?
How to host them in GridView?
For example: question
Widget host in Java and layouts in XML: host
Compose is around for years already and I am quite surprised.

You wouldn't host them in a GridView, because you don't (or at least try very hard not to) use views in Compose.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/glance/create-app-widget

@GabeSechan I would gladly skip that, but I have a requirement to show widgets in custom launcher and enable picking and moving around..

I didn't say you shouldn't show widgets.  I said you wouldn't use a GridView.  You can still show things in scrollable rows and columns in Compose, it just wouldn't use a View at all.  Probably some variation on LazyColumn.

I've never made a host in either framework, but it seems to translate to Compose just about like everything else does: https://gist.github.com/mlmayii/20336719244b556c7e51b41c1b46962e. Looks like https://i.sstatic.net/CbVUJ9kr.gif. You're right, though, that the documentation is lacking, but there's no decent documentation for this in Views, either, AFAICT.

may be you need it official documentation
https://developer.android.google.cn/develop/ui/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose

The links gives me Internal Server Error, are you sure it's correct?
